# Inherited a website with reference to fast.fonts.net - what is it?

Tags: javascript, api, fonts

I have a call to an offsite script (http://fast.fonts.net/jsapi/0f1b6603-bb67-4e35-aaae-301a9e1729f2.js) which I can only assume is some kind of preloader or CDN for the site's fonts. However - there is no frontend to this website (fonts.net) and no contact info from the WhoIs lookup.

Do I need this or is it defunct? An explanation of what this script actually does would also be useful! Cheers

It doesn't error in console (200 found), so the script exists.
There are a number of woff fonts included in the theme directory.
I have contacted fonts.com who say it isn't connected with them.

It's a SilverStripe site, currently being migrated to WP.

Comment: The script references http://api2.fonts.com when you go https://www.fonts.net it sends you an expired `fonts.com` cert. It really looks like it is connected to them. Also the wayback machine shows redirects for fonts.com.

Comment: Maybe the help desk doesn't know how everything is wired together. BTW it looks like you can get your same script via fonts.com: http://fast.fonts.com/jsapi/0f1b6603-bb67-4e35-aaae-301a9e1729f2.js

Answer (score 5):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54070663/inherited-a-website-with-reference-to-fast-fonts-net-what-is-it#comment94974084_54070663) comment is correct.

You can purchase web fonts from the website fonts.com and use them on your site either by downloading the font file or by using an external script or css link. In your case, you are using the latter option.

The subdomain fast.fonts.net points to their service that they use to deliver these fonts to your website.

You can see from the documentation https://www.fonts.com/web-fonts/instructions that the link generated is a fast.fonts.net link.